# Comparing fields and getting percentage

Tags: php, mysql

Hi and thank you again for looking into this question.

I have one mysql table for visitors. They can add their favorite singers to a list. So the table looks very simple:

```
user_artist_favorites
id
user_id
artistName
```

Let's say Moonwalker got 4 favorite singers:

```
 1. Michael Jackson
 2. Elvis Presley
 3. Ray Charles
 4. Stevie Wonder
```

The user Tester got also 4 favorite singers:

```
 1. Michael Jackson
 2. Ray Charles
 3. Stevie Wonder
 4. Lady Gaga (sorry folks)
```

What I would like to do now is compare the two users and output something like: Moonwalker & Tester have 75% the same taste in music.

How to start? Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: 75 % of what? That depends on your definition of this. Percentage is always relative.

Comment: Well if Tester had the same artists as Moonwalker, it would be 100%. Now he got 3 out of 4 so it's 75% of the total singers both users have in their favorite table. Or isn't that what you're asking?

Comment: I think you want to know how many singers are the same as a total %. Is the number of favourites always 4? Are the names exactly the same (ie. are they selected from a drop down list?) Also, are you after just comparing two users at a time?

Comment: @Rasika: That's exactly what I'm looking for yes. No the number of favourites may differ. Each user can add as many artists as he wants.
The names are exactly the same, they are inserted by me in the admin area.

Comment: @Rasika: Good question. I want just to compare the current logged in user, with users who are in the database. I would gladly start by comparing only the current user with another user in the database, but if it's possible to compare with different people it would be great.

Comment: I do not think it is the way..  select count() to the user and then compare... just it.

Comment: I understand you'd like to mark 100 % when they have exactly the same favorites and 0 % when they have no common favorites but what about this scenario: Alice likes 4 singers, Bob likes 9, they have 3 in common - is the percentage 75 % (compared to Alice's total) or is it only 33.3 % (compared to Bob's total)? Is really percentage the best possible metric here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select T1.user_id
    , Count( T2.user_id ) / Count( T1.user_id ) * 100.0 As PercentMatch
From user_artist_favorites As T1
    Left Join user_artist_favorites As T2
        On T2.artistname = T1.artistname
            And T2.user_id = 'Tester'
Where T1.user_id = 'Moonwalker'
Group By T1.user_id
Union All
Select T1.user_id
    , Count( T2.user_id ) / Count( T1.user_id ) * 100.0
From user_artist_favorites As T1
    Left Join user_artist_favorites As T2
        On T2.artistname = T1.artistname
            And T2.user_id = 'Moonwalker'
Where T1.user_id = 'Tester'
Group By T1.user_id
```

The first part of the Union All query returns the percent that Tester is like Moonwalker. The second query returns the percent that Moonwalker is like Tester.

Comment: This would compare only two users, but is a good start to think of a full SQL solution.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks a lot for the solution! I didn't try it yet, but it looks promising.

Comment: @Rasika - Granted. This is where MS SQL Server's Cross Apply is handy. It would allow you to select pairs of users and reference those inside the Union All query. Unfortunately, MySQL does not have any equivalent of which I know.

Comment: @Thomas, I had up voted yours as I knew that it was a good start. :)

Comment: +1. Great job Thomas. Just percent calculation alias is misleading cause it takes first one used for both rows but it can be solved easily.

Comment: @nick rulez: can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Change firt row count in this way   , count( T2.user_id ) / count( T1.user_id ) * 100.0 as Percent,'Percent_Tester_LIke_Moonwalker' as description and second row     , count( T2.user_id ) / count( T1.user_id ) * 100.0,'Percent_Moonwalker_Like_Tester'
Regards.

Comment: @nick rulez:
Thank you, but I get 0 back. The solution of Thomas works fine, but only for the first Select. When I try to echo the Percent_Moonwalker_Like_Tester row I get 0 as a response.

But I'm glad the first query is working fine. At least now I can compare two different users. Thanks a lot Thomas for the solution! And you too Nick and Rasika!

Comment: Hi. Unluckily it's difficult to put text inside a comment. I've uploaded to you a text file with my version.   http://myfreefilehosting.com/f/9fcc6f6853_0.1MB     Hope it helps. Regards. :)

Comment: @moonwalker - The problem is the alias. In a Union query, only the first query dictates the column names. I simply added the alias to make it clear what you were seeing. A better idea would be to use an alias of something like "PercentMatch" and forgo the second alias entirely.

Comment: @moonwalker - I adjusted the query to make it clearer. You should get two rows: one for each user. In the revised version, the column for the percentage will be called PercentMatch.

Comment: Thomas has done all the jobs. You're welcome... despite lady gaga ;)

Comment: Thomas:
Thank you very much for your explanation. I've learned a lot from you guys. Hopefully someday I can return the favor!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is read the lists sorted by artist name for the two users and go through a loop to count the number of singers that match. The loop will be a bit complicated as you need to check which list is alphabetically greater at the index and increase the pointer on the one that is lower.

Comment: Sounds complicated indeed. Thanks for the answer, I will try what you've suggested.